# invalid parameter exception on stripe payment creation

Tags: python, django

In the class below i am trying to create a stripe payment charge but i keep getting an exception that is in the except block (the stripe.error.InvalidRequestError) and it keeps telling me invalid parameters when i try to create a payment.

here is the class in views that has the except block.

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # equipment_order
        return render(self.request, "payment.html")

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        equipment_order = 
            models.EquipmentOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, 
            ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = int(equipment_order.get_total() * 100)

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
               amount=amount, #cents
               currency="usd", 
               source=token
            )

            # create payment
            payment = models.Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = equipment_order.get_total()
            payment.save()

            # assign payment to order
            equipment_order.ordered = True
            equipment_order.payment = payment
            equipment_order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful!")
            return redirect("create:equipment_home_page")

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            return redirect("create:equipment_home_page")

        ...
        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.error(self.request, "Invalid parameters")
            return redirect("create:equipment_home_page")
        ...
```

here is the payment class in models

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting? Stripe errors always contain a message telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: it is throwing the invalid parameters error. i have changed the api charge and it is still giving me the error

Comment: A `invalid_parameters_error` will have a human readable message attached to it: https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors. If you tell me what the message is I can probably point out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

add description field in stripe.Charge.create() function parameter

Comment: can you reformat your answer so that one see corrected code?

Comment: charge = stripe.Charge.create(
               amount=amount, #cents
               currency="usd", 
               source=token, description="my first charge"
            )